# How to use a custom error controller that is located in a plugin?

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, error-handling, cakephp-3.x

I have problem with my cakephp3 code. I'm using default `ErrorController.php`.

My problem is that I use a own plugin. There have also `ErrorController.php` and needed template files but this file not loading in plugin, plugin using default error controller from path `/`.

My files structure view like this:

- `/`
- `/src/Template/Layout/error.ctp`
- `/src/Template/Error/error400.ctp`
- `/src/Template/Error/error500.ctp`
- `/src/Controller/ErrorController.php`

In plugin I have this files:

- `/plugins/Plug/src/Template/Layout/error.ctp`
- `/plugins/Plug/src/Template/Error/error400.ctp`
- `/plugins/Plug/src/Template/Error/error500.ctp`
- `/plugins/Plug/src/Controller/ErrorController.php`

I need to get error from file: `/plugins/Plug/src/Controller/ErrorController.php`
but I still have output from `/src/Controller/ErrorController.php`

File `/plugins/Plug/src/Controller/ErrorController.php` view like this:

```
namespace Plug\Controller;

use Plug\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Event\Event;
class ErrorController extends AppController
{
    /**
     * Initialization hook method.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize()
    {
        echo "this line test using this file.";
        exit;
        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    }
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please take a look at [this](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/errors.html#extending-and-implementing-your-own-exception-handlers). You will see that you missed a lot of steps needed to be done

Comment: What's a little unclear from you question currently, is whether you are trying to use multiple error controllers for errors thrown in different parts of your application, or if you just want to use the plugin error controller applicaition wide, for all errors?